# Apache JENA TDB files locked after creation with web application

Tags: glassfish, jena, semantic-web, tdb

I am using JENA to create a triple store (TDB functionality) with the following code:

```
public void createTDBFromOWL() {
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(newTripleStoreLocation);

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);

    try {
        //getting the model inside the transaction
        Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
        FileManager fileManager=FileManager.get();
        Model holder=fileManager.readModel(model, newOWLFileLocation);

        //committing dataset
        dataset.commit();

        model.close();
        holder.close();
    } finally {
        dataset.end();
        dataset.close();
    }

}
```

After I create the triple store, the files created are locked by my application server (Glassfish), and I can't delete them until I manually stop Glassfish and it releases its lock.  As shown in the above code, I think I am closing everything, so I don't get why a lock is maintained on the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Dataset#close()`, the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/core/DatasetImpl.java#DatasetImpl.close%28%29) delegates that call to an underlying 
[`DatasetGraphBase#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/arq/2.8.3/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/core/DatasetGraphBase.java#DatasetGraphBase.close%28%29), which then ultimately delegates to [`DatasetGraphTDB#_close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/store/DatasetGraphTDB.java#DatasetGraphTDB._close%28%29).

This results in calls to [`TripleTable#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/store/TripleTable.java#TripleTable.close%28%29) and [`QuadTable#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/store/QuadTable.java#QuadTable.close%28%29). Both of these call (several) [`NodeTupleTable#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/nodetable/NodeTupleTable.java#NodeTupleTable.close%28%29). Continuing with the indirection, this calls [`NodeTable#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/nodetable/NodeTable.java#NodeTable) and [`TupleTable#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/index/TupleTable.java#TupleTable.close%28%29). The former is an interface, so we'd need to make a proper guess as to which class is run in your implementation. The latter iterates through a collection of [`TupleIndex`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/index/TupleIndex.java#TupleIndex) objects and calls `close()` on each of them. `TupleIndex` is, also, an interface.

There is only one meaningful heirarchy of descendents from `TupleIndex` that results in something which can lock a file, which leads us to [`TupleIndexRecord#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.hp.hpl.jena/tdb/0.8.5/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/index/TupleIndexRecord.java#TupleIndexRecord.close%28%29). We can then follow a particular implementation of `RangeIndex` called `BPlusTree` all the way down until we see actual ownership of the `MappedByteBuffer`

Ultimately, while reading the implementation of [`BlockAccessMapped#close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-tdb/1.0.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/tdb/base/file/BlockAccessMapped.java#BlockAccessMapped._close%28%29), it seems like the entire heirarchy is closing things properly, down to the final classes, but that [this longstanding bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724038) may be the culprit. From the documentation:

> once a file has been mapped a number of operations on that file will
>   fail until the mapping has been released (e.g. delete, truncating to a
>   size less than the mapped area). However the programmer can't control
>   accurately the time at which the unmapping takes place --- typically
>   it depends on the processing of finalization or a PhantomReference
>   queue.

So there you have it. Despite Jena's best efforts, one cannot yet control when that file will be unmapped in Java. This ends up being the tradeoff for memory-mapped file IO in java.

Comment: In particular if you are on Windows then unmapping of files is very unreliable